# How do I loop through an array within the data: of an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have an array of courses. I'm using Rapid API for the back-end. I want to loop through the array and equate if "course": [one of those elements in the array].

**sendEmail.js**

```
var courses = ["course1", "course2", "course3", "course4"];
var courseLoop;
var dayLoop;
jQuery.ajax({
url: "http://something-something.rapidapi.io/get-day",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
data: {
  "course":for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    courseLoop = courses[i];
    if("course" == courseLoop){
      alert("found");
      break;
    }
},
"day": "1",
},
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
alert("HTTP Request Succeeded: " + jqXHR.status);
console.log(data);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert("HTTP Request Failed");
})
.always(function() {
/* ... */
});
```

I know I'm way off, but this is where I've got till.

Comment: Can you edit your question and separate out the `data : { }` with real sample data you would pass via the POST...

Comment: You can use iffe:
"course":(function(courses,courseLoop){for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    courseLoop = courses[i];
    if("course" === courseLoop){
      alert("found");break;
    }}})(courses,courseLoop);

Comment: @RawAliasCoder this is the kind of thing I want. Can you put this in an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To evaluate if specific value present in your array or not you could use anonymous IIFE([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)).
It will be something like this:

```
var courses = ["course1", "course2", "course3", "course4"];
var courseLoop;
var dayLoop;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/echo/json/",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: {
      "course": (function(courses, courseLoop) {
        //in jquery you can use inArray
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          if ("course" === courses[i]) {
            courseLoop = courses[i];
            //alert("found");//Removing Blocking Call
            if (window.console && console.log) console.log('found');
            break;
          }
        }
        return courseLoop;
      }(courses, courseLoop)), //Douglas Crockford's style
      "day": "1"
    }
  })
  .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //alert("HTTP Request Succeeded: " + jqXHR.status);
    if (window.console && console.log) console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR, jqXHR.status);
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //alert("HTTP Request Failed");
    if (window.console && console.log) console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
  })
  .always(function() {

  });
```

Comment: So basically "course": "course3" will go through the done loop. I just wanted to iterate through my courses array and check for each one. Is this letting me do that? It's important for it to go through .done. Thanks so much for your help?

Comment: you have to change it in your own way.also you can check https://jsfiddle.net/SageGandhi/bxp2z8ut/

Answer (score 0):

The way to loop through arrays is basically

`.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    data.each(function(item) {
        if (item.courseTitle == 'blah') {
            console.log(item);
        }
    });
    console.log(data);
})`